# Persist Form Values in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, persistent-storage

A form on a page has inputs that needs its values to be persisted when a user navigates away and back to the form again. `mrt:garlic` package is used and the demo can be found [here on Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/E4d2BcQPf7C3zzn2x/Copy%20of%20Form%20Persistance).

Why does the form data values not persist? How would you persist form data in Meteor?

```
<template name="form">
  <form>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
  </form>
</template>


Template.form.rendered = function() {
    $('form').garlic()
}
```

Comment: your reproduction in meteorpad persists my input.  It did not work in meteorpad's in page browser but if I opened the link in a new browser window it worked.

Comment: @user728291 Yes you are right! Maybe it didnt work on my actual app because Iron Router was used to handle the route changes... Cant figure out how to use Iron Router routes in meteorpad yet

Answer (score 0):

Should ensure destroy your inputs of the template object.
From Garlic documentation:

> Destroy storage for an element (don't work on an entire form yet, only
>   input by input)

```
Template.form.destroyed = function () {
    $( 'input.no_good' ).garlic( 'destroy' );
};
```

Ref: http://garlicjs.org/